# Publishing VS2010 Web Solution to WordPress

Tags: visual-editor, publish

I am wondering if it's possible to publish a website that I have created onto WordPress? If so, how?

The site was created using VS2010.

I've done some searching online, and all I've came up with are tutorials on WordPress on how to publish your Visual Studio site onto other things not related to WordPress.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since the server side languages differ in both, you can not do such conversion in a straightforward manner or via any tool, easily.

The site that you have created in VS runs over .Net framework and written in .Net languages while the WordPress is in PHP.

The HTML,CSS,JS etc browser specific things you may be easily able to link into a WordPress site but the next challenge is functionality written in server side script. You will need to write all the functionality in PHP that you have written in C# or vb.Net etc. Also, in asp.Net, you can use so many controls which are converted in HTML on browser. But, here you will need to add rendered copy of the HTML. 
Then the biggest challenge is database structure. In your site, you would have your own defined database structure but WordPress has its own structure. The data will not be mapped directly. You will need to do proper integration by PHP and MySQL.